# Is listening to music composed for avodah zara assur in all contexts?

Tags: avodah-zarah, music

I read that R' Yisrael Moshe Hazan, the former chief Rabbi of Rome allowed for church tunes to be incorporated into nigunim for his community, and as a result many of the niggunim used contemporaneously by Italian Jews have their origins in church melodies. I wonder how it's possible that it is muttar for this custom to continue given that there's a halacha in Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 142:15 that it's assur to listen to music made for the purpose of avodah zara. As far as I know, no posek other than R' Yisrael Moshe Hazan was mattir for this practice and I'm curious as to whether or not it can be justified.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I don't understand the wording of your question. Would we not say that the custom can continue because it has the halachic basis that allowed it in the first place? RY"M Chazan's heter is the conclusion of a lengthy halachic discussion in his book כרך של רומי.

Comment: Rav Ovadya Yosef has a characteristically comprehensive teshuva about this in Yabia Omer. I don't remember where though, unfortunately.